# Rails: best practice to do versioning of content on mongo db (mongoid)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, versioning, mongoid

I need to build a simple content repository, but I need to be able to do basic versioning, any suggestion on how to tackle this the best way possible ?
A simple array of embedded content ? What's your take on this ?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think mongoid already has versioning support. Please read the versioning part in here:
http://mongoid.org/docs/extras

Comment: Right sorry I should have detailed more. I need to some some things that I can't seem to be able to do with mongoid versioning. Somehow sometime I need to skip saving a version. I looked into skipping callback but can't find how to do it with mongoid...

Answer (score 0):

Well actually, I was wrong, I can totally do what I wanted. Playing with the call back saved the day :)

```
 def no_versioning_set_status(status_symbol)
   Content.skip_callback(:save, :before, :revise)
   self.set_status(status_symbol)
   Content.set_callback(:save, :before, :revise)
 end
```